# WAR will not deploy to Tomcat 7.0.19

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, war, web.xml

I have a WAR that Tomcat will not deploy, and whereas it normally gives me the reason or some indication as to why it won't deploy the app, Tomcat's catalina log output simply states:

> SEVERE: Context [/appmon-qa] startup failed due to previous errors

Here's is the `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <!-- The display name of this web application -->
    <display-name>AppMonitor</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.me.myorg.appmon.AppMonitor
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

And the important stuff inside that `AppMonitor` class:

```
public class AppMonitor implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        try {
            // Guts of my monitor app
        } catch(Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("Something bad happened!\n" + exc.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the remarkably vague/undescriptive log output:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive appmon-qa.war
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/appmon-qa] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8010"]
Jun 8, 2012 9:45:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2875 ms
```

I undeployed this WAR and deployed another one that I know works fine and Tomcat 7.0.19 launched it without any problems, so I **know** its not a Tomcat/configuration issue. This is clearly something wrong with my WAR. Directory structure is as follows:

```
appmon-qa.war/
    META-INF/
        MANIFEST.MF
    WEB-INF/
        classes/
            All of my binaries
        lib/
            All JAR dependencies
        web.xml
```

If there was something wrong with my (super-simple) `web.xml`, Tomcat *should* be complaining in the log output. If my `web.xml/ServletContextListener` was fine, but something was throwing an exception inside my `contextInitialized` method, the `catch` block would be printing the message to the console - but that's not happening.

Any ideas as to what could be the underlying problem or what options I have to start diagnosing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it should be public void contextDestroyed. is that a typo?

Comment: Is it really `public contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)`? Where is the `void`?

Comment: Yep sorry about that - it was a typo - edited!

Comment: Don't just catch the exception and print it to console, re-throw it.

Comment: @adarshr - I thought of that too and tried it but to no avail - nothing changes :-(

Comment: What about `localhost-xxxx.log`?

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/tomcat-6-infamous-%E2%80%9Csevere

Comment: http://mythinkpond.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/tomcat-6-infamous-severe-error-listenerstart-message-how-to-debug-this-error/

Comment: Show us your web.xml. And start commenting out things like listeners and servlets that have load at startup on, one by one....

Comment: web.xml is at start of my original question...?!?

Comment: Try setting 2.4 and 2_4 in web.xml to 3.0 and 3_0 respectively. Thats a very old version you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the super class in your methods.

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        super.contextInitialized(servletContextEvent);
```

....
    }

and

```
   @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        super.contextDestroyed(servletContextEvent);
    }
```

As an extra you could make sure to increase the log level on your tomcat server (maybe integrate log4j)
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Mihai